# VB.NEt SpVoice / SAPI always first in action

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys i want to get some help.. because my program "BINGO caller" the SAPI/SpVoice is always speaking first before displaying the value in my textbox. and other problem is while speaking the SAPI all buttons and commands are not functioning they become ok when the SAPI is done speaking and the number they speak is showing in texbox after the speak. please help me.. i want to my program is displaying the number while SAPI speak the value in my textbox. please help me. this is my code in displaying the Number and letter in textbox and this is the code in SAPI

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    nos = randomarray(index)
    index = index + 1

    If nos <= 15 And nos >= 1 Then
        col = "B"
    ElseIf nos <= 30 And nos >= 16 Then
        col = "I"
    ElseIf nos <= 45 And nos >= 31 Then
        col = "N"
    ElseIf nos <= 60 And nos >= 46 Then
        col = "G"
    ElseIf nos <= 75 And nos >= 61 Then
        col = "O"
    End If

    lbl_no.Text = nos
    lbl_let.Text = col

    sVar = Mid(nos, 1, 1)
    sVar2 = Mid(nos, 2)

    CType(Me.Controls("lbl_" & nos.ToString), Label).BackColor = Color.Yellow

    If index = randomarray.Count Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        btn_pause.Enabled = False
        btn_clear.Show()
        btn_exit.Hide()
    End If 

    voice()
    txt_count.Text = index - 1

End Sub
```

This is the SAPI code

```
Sub voice()
    Dim VObj As Object
    VObj = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

    With VObj
        .Volume = 100
        .Rate = -2
        .Speak(col & " " & nos)
        .Speak(col & " " & sVar & " " & sVar2)
    End With
End Sub
```

[This is my Screenshot of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0wVC.png)

Comment: try adding a `Application.DoEvents()` before calling the `Voice()` method call and I would also move the `txt_count.Text = index - 1` before the `Voice()` method call

Comment: The problem is because the speaking library is using the main thread thus freezing everything until it finishes. The ideal solution would be to have it run on a different thread. Try searching for `.net Tasks` :) `Tasks.Run(AddressOf Voice)`

Comment: can you please give me some example... thank you... i dont have any idea for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of calling voice() on the ui thread just call it on a thread pool thread.

```
'voice()
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf voice)
```

Comment: No, like I posted in my answer. Use addressof voice. That will tell the thread to call that sub when it is ready.

Comment: No problem. If this resolved your issue then please tick the answer as accepted.